# Using parallel in spatraster and writing

Tags: parallel-processing, terra

I have observation with 12 layers and a list (1440) of future models. I have done calculations, e.g. added/multiplied each layer from observation to the respective layer in the future models. Since it takes time to write the files and save, I have used `foreach()`. To do this, I had to convert the output to rasterbrick as I did not know how to do it in `terra`. Could anyone help me how I can do the same calculation in `terra`? Below is my code:

```r
# Perform calculation
tasmax_down <- obs + mod_rast
names(tasmax_down) <- names(mod_rast)

# Covert spatraster to rasterbrick 
tasmax_brick <- raster::brick(tasmax_down)

# Parallel process
cl <- makeCluster(10)
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i = 1:nlayers(tasmax_brick)) %dopar% {
  r <- raster::raster(tasmax_brick, i)
  raster::writeRaster(r, filename = paste0("E:/Downscale/", gsub("\\.", "-", 
                                                                 names(tasmax_brick[[i]])), ".tif"),
                      format = "GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: It is important to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. We don't have access to your tasmax_brick object, so please provide some data we can work with. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Also, SO is not a code writing service, so it is not enough to ask how to convert your code. Please include what you have tried in `terra` so far. Thanks.